# Send SMS using Node JS without a 3rd party service

Tags: node.js, sms

Is there a way we can send a text message in SMS format to a phone number from our nodejs web application? I know there are multiple free/paid third party services which allow you to do the same but is it possible to do it independently? I know it sounds like re-inventing the wheel but I would like to understand the challenges or advantages involved.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment to other carriers, but many many years ago you could text a phone via SMS with a pseudo email for some carriers. For example, I just tested this on my carrier -- which is Verizon -- and it still works. You can send an email to the phone number plus "@vtext.com" and it will go to that phone number's text message. For example, if my Verizon mobile number is 8755551212 I can email 8755551212@vtext.com and the phone will get the email content as a text message. I don't know if other carriers do this.

Comment: You're still relying on vtext.com, which seems like another 3rd party service

Answer (score 0):

You can connect GSM modem to your server hosting the nodeJS code.

Then use NPM package for serial/usb communication and send AT commands directly to USB modem.
Here is one library https://www.npmjs.com/package/serial-at